# cities_light don't have all the cities in my country? DJANGO

Tags: python, django, database

I would like to know how to load all the data in cities_light of Django, I have 42 record when I run `python manage.py cities_light --force-import-all` or `python manage.py cities_light`

in settings

```
CITIES_LIGHT_TRANSLATION_LANGUAGES = ['es']
CITIES_LIGHT_INCLUDE_COUNTRIES = ['CR']
```

This return 42 records in /cities but I need more than 100

I would like to know how charge more records in the database becouse I have so much code to change if I change cities_light for another library.
I thought that I could make a script for charge the rest of the records for instance a csv, but I need the obligatory fields in the database.

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Cities Light uses the open [Geonames](http://www.geonames.org/) database. So it only knows the cities that are in the Geonames database. You can help and add missing cities there or fix the data on existing entries.

Also, there are [different data files for cities](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/readme.txt) from Geonames.

- `cities1000.zip` has all cities with a population >1000
- `cities5000.zip` all cities with a population >5000
- `cities15000.zip` all cities with a population >15000

So maybe you are importing the smallest file that includes only larger towns and cities.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, but I see that geonames have a lot of cities in CR (Costa Rica), but I don't know how to load all the records, I have only 42 and when I run python manage.py cities_light --force-import-all It don't show any error :/

Comment: Its the opposite of what you're saying my friend @C14L cities1000.zip contains more than cities15000.zip

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/[Country_Code].zip`
It's the only way I found to load more cities.

You may need to update the CITIES_LIGHT_INCLUDE_CITY_TYPES variable see
**http://www.geonames.org/export/codes.html**.

*I Hope that this will help someone because it took me sometime to figure all this out*